# Using placeholder in a update form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, placeholder

I want to replace the default value of a `text_field` in a update form by a `placeholder`. How can I do that ?
My first thought was the following code but the default value of the `text_field` is still here :

```rb
<%= form_for(some) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.text_field :thing, placeholder: "what an example !" %></div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **text_field_tag**

```
<%= form_for(some) do |f| %>
    <div>
      <%= text_field_tag "some_thing", (some.thing unless some.thing=="default value"), :name=> "some[thing]", :placeholder => "what an example !" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Hope, it will work..

Thanks